# Prove the expectation converges to zero

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with $E(X) < +\infty$. We have a sequence of events $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, satisfying $P(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

How can we prove the expectation is also converging to zero, 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X \mathbb{1}_{A_n}) = 0,
$$
 where $\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ is the indicator function of $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is a corollary of the following fact.

> Suppose $E[|X|] < \infty$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $E[|X| \mathbb{1}_{B}] < \epsilon$ for every set $P(B) < \delta$.

Proof of this fact:

For positive integers $M$ we define $A_M := \{|X| \le M\}$.
Note that $(|X| \mathbb{1}_{A_M})_M$ is a monotone nondecreasing sequence that converges to $|X|$ pointwise.
By the monotone convergence theorem, there exists $M_0$ such that
$$E[|X|(1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_{M_0}})] < \epsilon / 2.$$

Now, choose $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{2 M_0}$.
If $P(B) < \delta$, then
\begin{align}
E[|X| \mathbb{1}_B]
&= E[|X|\mathbb{1}_B(1 - \mathbb{1}_{ A_{M_0}})]
+ E[|X|(\mathbb{1}_{B \cap A_{M_0}})]
\\
&\le E[|X|(1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_{M_0}})]
+ M_0 P(B)
\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
\end{align}